# Get Model property in PHP

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I want to get property name of `Model` class in PHP. In java I can do like this one:

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Field field : Model.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(field.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
id
name
```

How can I do that in PHP?

**Model.php**

```
<?php 

    class Model {
        private $id;
        private $name;

        public function __get($property) {
            if(property_exists($this, $property))
                return $this->$property;
        }

        public function __set($property, $value) {
            if(property_exists($this, $property))
                $this->$property = $value;

            return $this;
        }
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    # How to loop and get the property of the model like in Main.java above?
?>
```

## Update Solution

**Solution 1:**

```
<?php

    include 'Model.php';

    $model = new Model();

    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($model);
    $props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);

    foreach ($props as $prop) {
        print $prop->getName() . "\n";
    }
?>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<?php

    include 'Model.php';

    $rc = new ReflectionClass('Model');
    $properties = $rc->getProperties();

    foreach($properties as $reflectionProperty) {
        echo $reflectionProperty->name . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`ReflectionClass::getProperties`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)?

*Available in PHP >= 5*

Also available, [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

*Available in PHP 4 & 5*

Both documentation pages list examples, but if you have trouble update your question or ask a different question with the specific problem you're having (and show what you've tried).

Comment: Just making sure you know --- I see too many people forget :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's in-built Reflection features, just as you do in Java.

```
<?php
$rc = new ReflectionClass('Model');
$properties = $rc->getProperties();
foreach($properties as $reflectionProperty)
{
    echo $reflectionProperty->name;
}
```

See the PHP manual on [reflection here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).